# How to add bump to shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I have a simple diffuse shader. I would like to add some bump to it. How can I do this in Cycles? Where do I plug in my checkered texture.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Per shader:

Plug it it into the *Height* input of a *Bump* node (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*>Add node > Vector > Bump*)

[image]

The above node setup will only bump the diffuse part of the shader, simulating a bumpy diffuse surface coated with a smooth glossy "glaze" layer.

[image]

## Entire material:

If you want to apply the same bump mapping to all the shaders in your material, just plug it into the *Displace* input of the *Material output* node:

[image]

You'll notice that now the bump is applied to the glossy shader too:

[image]