# How to get this bump shader effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

This is a follow on question asked previously but how so I get this exact effect, (including the depth of the checker squares)

[image: Checher bump map]

Original question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/how-to-add-bump-to-shader/150590#150590).

Comment: This would be so easy to do procedurally if blender just had a blur node in the materials.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to do it procedurally but here is a way to do it with a normal bake:

- Built your pattern, it's like half pyramids that merge each others. Use the *Mirror* modifier as it's completely symmetrical.

[image]

- Give your object 2 *Array* modifiers to make a whole grid. Also add a *Subdivision Surface* and Shading Smooth it.

[image]

- Now create a plane, put it above your grid, unwrap and bake the normals.

[image]

- Use the normal map on the object you want. As your surface seems a bit glossy, mix a *Glossy* with a *Diffuse*, and don't forget to plug the Normal map in both these 2 nodes.

[image]

Comment: Just confirming that your comment _"Use the normal map on the object you want"_ means I can use it on a sphere object, as in the example? _Great answer BTW._

Comment: It's not clear how it is mapped on your sphere on your picture

Comment: Can I have a look at your mirror modifer setup please, I am trying to make use of the mirror modifier in the modeling, (not used it before)

Comment: here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6526" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6526/)

Comment: The answer is great, and I upvoted it.  I think it would be better if you explained how you baked the map (I know how you did, but a lot of other people don't) :)

Comment: thanks. About the bake: I understand but I think it can easily be found somewhere else, plus it would be very tedious to explain every little step of the process. Also, the person who asked the question doesn't seem to care a lot  ;)

Comment: Actually I do care :). But noted about the tedious nature of logging everything, it's just that even with the file could you believe I hadn't quite got my head around the actual way it was done! Thanks anyway moonboots, your help was appreciated thus far.

Comment: oh ok sorry, I didn't even realized we talked together  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add a diplace modifier and apply a normal map to the shader to get the same bump effect.

Please refer to the screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not blurred checker texture in the displace, it is regular noise.

Comment: I'm obviously miszsing something. But this doesn't quite look like the OP bump?